# Regular expression to match a character set but negate a sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a sequence of separators but negate whenever an hyphen as a character before and after as such:

For example `[\u002D\u0020]` will match all spaces and hyphens.

> I have wi-fi

However, I want wi-fi to not be a match since it has a letter character before and after. (e.g. `\w+\u002D\w+`)

How do I negate a sequence while matching a character set?
Also, is \w limited to latin letter characters? Is the engine aware of the cultures, arabic and turkish for example ?

EDIT:
Just to explain further what I'm trying to achieve.
I want to collect all punctuation and specific characters from a sentence and ignore all words (e.g. -+#$%, etc).

Whenever there's an hyphenated word (e.g. state-of-the-art) I wish to ignore the whole word. "this is# a %state-of-the-art design" I intend to get the following collection: "#, %".

Comment: `Is the engine aware of the cultures` unfortunately not which is not really good when you want international stuff. There are regex libraries like XRegExp, which do work with those.

Comment: Can you put sample data about what is your expected valid matches and non valid matches?

Comment: In JS, `\w` is not Unicode aware.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I want to collect all words from a sentence and ignore punctuation and specific characters (e.g. -+#$%, etc). Whenever there's an hyphenated word (e.g. state-of-the-art) I wish to collect the whole word. "this is# a %state-of-the-art design" I intend to get the following collection: "this, is, a, state-of-the-art, design"

Comment: @pelican_george, thanks.. I've updated the answer for your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching all hyphenated words and match and *capture* non-word chars in all other contexts using [`XRegExp`](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp):

```js
var s = "this is# a %statè-òf-thè-árt or state-of-the-art design";
var rx = XRegExp("\\p{L}+(?:-\\p{L}+)+|([^\\p{L}\\p{N}_ ])","g");
var res = [];
XRegExp.forEach(s, rx, function(match, i) {
    if (match[1]) res.push(match[1]);
});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

The pattern matches:

- `\\p{L}+(?:-\\p{L}+)+` one or more letters (`\\p{L}+`) followed with 1 or more sequences of `-` and 1+ letters again
- `|` - or
- `([^\\p{L}\\p{N}_ ])` - Group 1 capturing one char other than space, `_`, letters (`\\p{L}`) and digits (`\\p{N}`).

Only the contents of Group 1 should be pushed to the resulting array.

Comment: I might overcomplicated it a  bit: `var rx = XRegExp("\\p{L}-\\p{L}|([^\\p{L}\\p{N}_ ])","g");` might also work for you.

Comment: Is it possible to load just the categories addon to avoid loading the whole library (220kb). I'm just using raw html with no module nor bundling tools.

Comment: I do not know if you can load it partially, but theoretically, you can just use the category regexps from [the GitHub source code](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/src/addons/unicode-categories.js#L61).